# Best way to create and initialize a `HashMap<Date, Date>` in Java in code?

Tags: java, date, dictionary, hashmap

It will consists of entries like:

```
{{Date(2014, 1, 1), Date(2013, 11, 31)},
 {Date(2014, 1, 11), Date(2013, 11, 31)},
 {Date(2014, 1, 21), Date(2013, 11, 31)},
 {Date(2014, 1, 31), Date(2013, 11, 31)}}
```

I am currently using this:

```
public static Map<Date, Date> dateMap = new HashMap<Date, Date>(){{
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2014, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    cal2.set(2013, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0);
    put(cal.getTime(), cal2.getTime());
    cal.set(2014, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0);
    put(cal.getTime(), cal2.getTime());
    cal.set(2014, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0);
    put(cal.getTime(), cal2.getTime());
    cal.set(2014, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0);
    put(cal.getTime(), cal2.getTime());
}};
```

Comment: From where are you getting your values? The answer will depend on wheter or not you get it from a db, user input, a stored array, etc..

Comment: `Map<Date,Date> map = new HashMap<>()`

Comment: I need to initialize HashMap in Java Code itself. Values are not fetched from any source but directly provided in Code. It will be used for testing some util functions I have written.

Comment: @vaibhavvc1092 can you please more elaborate ?

Comment: Side note: consider to use the new Date & Time API introduced in Java SE 8 instead of using the legacy Date and Calendar classes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the **deprecated** [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-int-int-) constructor you used doesn't recognize a month with numeric value `12`. December is represented as `11`, so date `Date(2013, 12, 31)` will cause a recalculation.

Secondly, you can now use Java 8's [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to make your scenario easier.

Example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Buhake Sindi
 * @since 03 September 2015
 *
 */
public class Test {

    private static LocalDate[][] localDates = {{LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2013, 12, 31)},
                                                {LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 11), LocalDate.of(2013, 12, 31)},
                                                 {LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 21), LocalDate.of(2013, 12, 31)},
                                                 {LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 31), LocalDate.of(2013, 12, 31)}};
    private static Map<Date, Date> dates = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (LocalDate[] _localDates : localDates) {
            dates.put(Date.from(_localDates[0].atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()), Date.from(_localDates[1].atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dates);
    }
}
```

Note that month in `LocalDate` starts from `1` (January) to `12` (December) and not like `Date` which is from `0` (January) and `11` (December).

Comment: And the OP should try to omit the legacy Date class altogether, if possible.

Comment: Not really. JPA, for example, uses the "legacy" `Date` class to map SQL DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP. Until they include the newer `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, etc., we are stuck with it.

Comment: isn't this solution very likely to fail his tests, if they rely on specific values in `Date`? as this will provide different `Date` values, depending on the local time zone of where the code gets executed.

Comment: The OP's example  uses the Calendar's default Timezone, which also what `ZoneId.systemDefault()` does.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi That's why I wrote "if possible". The use case is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
int[] dateValues = { 2014, 1,  1, 2013, 12, 31,
                     2014, 1, 11, 2013, 12, 31,
                     2014, 1, 21, 2013, 12, 31,
                     2014, 1, 31, 2013, 12, 31 };
Map<Date, Date> map = new HashMap<>();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < dateValues.length; i += 6) {
    cal.set(dateValues[i], dateValues[i + 1] - 1, dateValues[i + 2]);
    Date key = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(dateValues[i + 3], dateValues[i + 4] - 1, dateValues[i + 5]);
    map.put(key, cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");

String [][] input = {{ "2014/01/01", /* ----> */ "2013/12/31" },
                     { "2014/01/11", /* ----> */ "2013/12/31" },
                     { "2014/01/21", /* ----> */ "2013/12/31" },
                     { "2014/01/31", /* ----> */ "2013/12/31" }};

Map<Date,Date> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String [] in : input)
{
    map.put(sdf.parse(in[0]), sdf.parse(in[1]));
}
```

Comment: That's hardly Java syntax. And if you were thinking of adding keyword `new`, then you'd realize that you're using deprecated constructors. New code should **not** use deprecated methods.

Comment: @Andreas ok, what do you suggest then?

Comment: Really? It shows **8** syntax errors when I paste it into an editor.

Comment: @Andreas okay, I forgot to add `new`, and I used `SimpleDateFormat` to fix the deprecated constructor

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it, this one parses the date from strings which makes them more readable:

```
static final Map<Date, Date> dm;

static {
    try {
        dm = new HashMap<Date, Date>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        {
            put(sdf.parse("2014-1-1"), sdf.parse("2013-12-31"));
            put(sdf.parse("2014-1-11"), sdf.parse("2013-12-31"));
            put(sdf.parse("2014-1-21"), sdf.parse("2013-12-31"));
            put(sdf.parse("2014-1-31"), sdf.parse("2013-12-31"));
        }};
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


@Test
public void datemap() {
    System.out.println(dm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modern way to initialize the map**

based on OPs solution and *Buhake Sindi*s answer (requires Java 1.8)

```
private static Date toGlobal(final LocalDate local) {
    return Date.from(local.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}

public static final Map<Date, Date> DATES;
static {
    DATES = new HashMap<Date, Date>() {{
            final Date value = toGlobal(LocalDate.of(2013, 12, 31));

            put(toGlobal(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1)), value);
            put(toGlobal(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 11)), value);
            put(toGlobal(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 21)), value);
            put(toGlobal(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 31)), value);
        }
    };
}
```

This might be a nice way to initialize the map, but is probably unsuited for a testing environment, as it leads to different `Date` values, depending on the local time-zone of where the code is executed.

**Old way, providing fixed/stable values**

```
public static final Map<Date, Date> DATES;
static {
    DATES = new HashMap<Date, Date>() {
    {
            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(2013, 11, 31);
            final Date value = cal.getTime();

            cal.set(2014, 0, 1);  put(cal.getTime(), value);
            cal.set(2014, 0, 11); put(cal.getTime(), value);
            cal.set(2014, 0, 21); put(cal.getTime(), value);
            cal.set(2014, 0, 31); put(cal.getTime(), value);
        }
    };
}
```

This is probably better suited for unit testing.